# Share types/models from service reference to client

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, blazor, webassembly

I am developing a blazor webassembly program with a web api backend. The backend uses a WCF service reference.
How can i share the types/models generated by the WCF service reference with the webassembly program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create the client proxy in a different project. I don't remember any options in VS, you may have to use the command line tool.

But I wouldn't.

The generated code usually isn't the prettiest, with lots of metadata, dependencies and properties you don't need or want in your SPA.

So consider writing a layer of DTO classes in a shared project and use AutoMapper to convert the data.

DTOs are Data Transfer Objects, the shared code between Client and Server. In your Client you can use them as Models and/or ViewModels.

Comment: +1. The SPA doesn't need to know the remote service's intricacies or have to handle version changes. Nor should it have to use the browser's limited resources to transform the DTOs into something it can use.

Comment: About versioning, there's a certain company in the air travel industry which considers XSD complimentary documentation as it generates SOAP responses using Node. So the actual responses can change without notice (they have a monthly release cycle) due to typos, or string elements becoming arrays. That's no job for a poor SPA

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly I should define the models in a shared project and create a mapping between my models and the WCF types on the backend?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can fit the DTOs to the task.